# Is it possible to enable word wrap to all editors in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

It is a little time consuming and distractive  to just enable word wrap when I open a new java file.Is there an option to have word wrap enabled by default? Or an option to enable it in all opened editors?

Comment: How do you enable it?

Comment: @AleksandrM You can use the shortcut alt+shift+y ,or you can click its icon from the tool bar .

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.